# Draw JFrame immediately

Tags: java, swing

I have `class LevenbergForm extends JFrame` and a function `calculate()` in it.

Generally speaking, there is a `for` loop in that function and on every iteration I need to create a `new JFrame`, show it and wait until button is pressed.

The problem i got is `JFrame` is not drawing it's components. It is all white inside. And only draws when the fucntion `calculate()` is over.

How to make `JFrame` draw itself while i'm still in that `for` loop?

And how to stop it until the `button` is pressed? (optional)

```
void calculate(boolean stepByStep) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        //...
        graph = new JFrame();
        graph.setContentPane(chartPanel);
        graph.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        graph.pack();
        graph.setVisible(true);
        graph.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //Draw JFrame and stop for loop until button pressed          
        //...   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a JFrame which on creation and showing is non-blocking. Instead use a modal dialog such as a JOptionPane which **does** block the current thread's flow until it has been dealt with.

Having said that, yours is an inconvenient and potentially annoying program design. Why not instead simply use a Swing Timer to change the state of a displayed JLabel's text?

Comment: can i somehow draw a picture on JOptioanPane?

Comment: @Zergay: absolutely. The 2nd parameter is an object parameter, and you can pass in either a JPanel with a drawing, or an ImageIcon with your picture.

Answer (score 0):

You also might consider running calculate on a thread other than the EDT. You could use code (untested) something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    calculate();
}
public static void calculate() {
    for ( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
        // calculations go here... not on EDT!!
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            // create and show JFrame
        });
    }
}
```

Or probably better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
        // create and show JFrame
    });
    calculate();
}
public static void calculate() {
    for ( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
        // calculations go here... not on EDT!!
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            // update JFrame
        });
    }
}
```

This solution will not block for user input, but it will show the JFrame before the calculate method is complete. If you wish for the calculations to be controlled by the button press then I suggest you invert control: have the button press fire an event that performs one step in the calculations.